# Doubts on obtaining orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, orthonormal, orthogonal-matrices

In finding the matrix $P$ that orthogonally diagonalizes $A$ and to determine $P^TAP$, where $$A = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
    -1 & 1 & -1 & 1\\
    1 & -1 & 3 & 1\\
    -1 & 1 & 1 & 3\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

I've found the eigenvalues to be $0$ and $4$.

In order to find the orthonormal basis, i've considered two scenarios where $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda = 4$:

For $\lambda = 0$, on solving the system, we have $    \begin{pmatrix}
w\\
x\\
y\\
z\\
    \end{pmatrix} $ = $s    \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
0\\
0\\
    \end{pmatrix} $ + $t    \begin{pmatrix}
2\\
0\\
-1\\
1\
    \end{pmatrix} $

For $\lambda = 0$, on solving the system, we have $    \begin{pmatrix}
w\\
x\\
y\\
z\\
    \end{pmatrix} $ = $s    \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}\\
-\frac{1}{2}\\
1\\
0\\
    \end{pmatrix} $ + $t    \begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2}\\
0\\
1\\
    \end{pmatrix} $

**My Doubts:**

1. As for $E_{4}$ as seen above, the answer considers the set of $    \begin{pmatrix}
   \frac{1}{2}\\
   -\frac{1}{2}\\
   1\\
   0\\
       \end{pmatrix} $, $    \begin{pmatrix}
   -1\\
   1\\
   0\\
   2\\
       \end{pmatrix} $ to be the basis for $E_{4}$. However, why is there a need to scale the basis by two into its integer basis of $    \begin{pmatrix}
   -1\\
   1\\
   0\\
   2\\
       \end{pmatrix} $ from $    \begin{pmatrix}
   -\frac{1}{2}\\
   \frac{1}{2}\\
   0\\
   1\\
       \end{pmatrix} $. Isn't it the same?
2. The answers present the orthonormal basis set of $E_{0}$ as $    \begin{pmatrix}
   \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\
   \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\
   0\\
   0\\
       \end{pmatrix} $, $    \begin{pmatrix}
   \frac{1}{2}\\
   -\frac{1}{2}\\
   -\frac{1}{2}\\
   \frac{1}{2}\\
       \end{pmatrix} $ and the orthonormal basis set for $E_{4}$ as $    \begin{pmatrix}
   \frac{1}{\sqrt6}\\
   -\frac{1}{\sqrt6}\\
   \frac{2}{\sqrt6}\\
   0\\
       \end{pmatrix} $, $    \begin{pmatrix}
   -\frac{1}{\sqrt12}\\
   \frac{1}{\sqrt12}\\
   \frac{1}{\sqrt12}\\
   \frac{3}{\sqrt12}\\
       \end{pmatrix} $

They stated that the orthonormal basis can be found by using the Gram-Schmidt Process. However, i'm not really sure how it can be computed. As for $E_{0}$, isn't it true that we divide each integer by $\sqrt (1^2 + 1^2)$ to get $    \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\
0\\
0\\
    \end{pmatrix} $ and $\sqrt (2^2+-1^2+1^2)$ to get  $    \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{2}{\sqrt6}\\
0\\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt6}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt6}\\
    \end{pmatrix} $ but it was apparently not the case as seen above. Why is that so?

Thanks.

Comment: Remember, you need the basis vectors for $E_0$ to be orthogonal to each other. That's where Gram-Schmidt comes in.

Comment: Eigenvectors from different eigenspaces will be orthogonal (and you can see this in your example). However, eigenvectors in the same eigenspace need not be orthogonal, and in this case they are not (not yet anyway). So we can use Gram-Schmidt to make the eigenvectors in $E_0$ orthogonal to one another, and similarly for $E_4$. We cannot simply normalize the vectors, because we also need to make them orthogonal.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Please elaborate on that. I've found the basis vectors to be of $(1,1,0,0)^T$ and $(2,0,-1,1)^T$. Isn't it just simple normalization by dividing by its norm?

Comment: You write about an orthonormal basis. Part of the definition of orthonormal is orthogonal. The two vectors you have just written down are not orthogonal, a fortiori, they can't be part of an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two vectors $u_1$ and $u_2$, the Gram-Schmidt algorithm produces two vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ defined by
$$
v_1 = \frac{u_1}{\|u_1\|}
\quad
v_2 = \frac{u_2 - (u_2|v_1)v_1}{\|u_2 - (u_2|v_1) v_1\|}
$$